# Idatareaders not returning values from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enterprise-library, datareader

In my codebehind I have this vb:

```
 Dim reader as idatareader = includes.SelectDepartmentID(PageID)
        While reader.Read
            Did = reader("departmentid")
            GroupingHeading = reader("heading")
            Folder = reader("folder")
            If reader("OwnBanner") Is DBNull.Value Then
                OwnBanner = String.Empty
            Else
                OwnBanner = reader("ownbanner")
            End If
```

Then in my class I have:

```
 Public Function SelectDepartmentID(ByVal PageID As Integer) As IDataReader
        Dim Command As SqlCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("sql")
        db.AddInParameter(Command, "@pageid", Data.DbType.Int32, PageID)
        Dim reader As IDataReader = db.ExecuteReader(Command)
        reader.Read()
        Return reader
    End Function
```

No Errors are being presented yet nothing is being returned by the reader. Is there an error in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: `idatareader`... That's why I hate VB.NET

Comment: I was using sqldatareaders but there is a problem returning them in the entlib!!! very frustrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the

```
reader.Read()
```

line from SelectDepartmentID.

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping the first row of the reader. Remove the `reader.Read()` statement in the `SelectDepartmentID` function just prior to the return statement.

Any function that returns a reader should make no assumptions about what the calling code will do with it and just return it unmodified.